# Infopath form doesn't close

Tags: infopath

I have an Infopath form and published to the forms library and a workflow running on the forms library. I want to send an email to the user with the link to the Infopath form.

I tried current items encoded URL and workflow context current item URL. This works fine when there are no attachments. When I attach a file using attachments control on my Infopath form and click submit, it has to save data to library and close the form.

In general, when I click submit, the data gets saved and form closes. But when I attach a file and click submit, data gets saved to the library but the form doesn't close.

Comment: Did you check ULS Logs and see if there were any errors related to InfoPath Services? If nothing helps then please elaborate the situation and provide more details on your rules and I will try to replicate this at my end

Comment: I cannot check the ULS logs, i do not have access to it. Problem explained in detail: I have an infopath form with attachment control on it. When I share the infopath form using Share option in Office 365 SharePoint site, email is sent to the user. When the user opens the infopath form, attaches a file and clicks on Save then close form from ribbon, the form doesnt close, it reloads.

Comment: I noticed that my infopath form works well with attachments when the form is opened from the library. But when the form is opened from the link in the email, it fails to close on adding attachments. I also noticed a difference in url's. When the form is opened from library url looks like http://site/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/site/libraryname/filename.xml&ClientInstalled=true&DefaultItemOpen=1&Source=http://site/libraryname/forms/allitems.aspx., when opened from link in email the url looks like http://site/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/site/libraryname/filename.xml

Comment: I hardcoded the &ClientInstalled=true&DefaultItemOpen=1&Source=http://site/libraryname/forms/allitems.aspx part in my email and now it works fine with attachments